# How to View local Meteor web app in mobile like browsersync

Tags: javascript, meteor, browser, browser-sync

How can i testing my Meteor app in mobile browser?
Like BrowserSync with the address ip.

Comment: If you are in a local network just start Meteor on your PC, find out what ip-address you have. Then open the browser on your mobilephone or tablet and enter that ip-address and add the port (e.g. 192.168.1.131:3000).

Comment: @ant45de I'm looking for the better way.

Comment: I think the question is unclear. Do you want to just _view_ your local app, or _test_ it via some automated test tool?

Comment: @HubertOG I just want view local Meteor we app in the mobile browser.

Comment: Define 'better'... I think you don't what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ant45de is correct. This is exactly what I do when wanting to view the WEB version of my app on my mobile phones browser.

First, find your local ip:
Windows: http://www.bobborst.com/tools/whatsmyip/
Mac/Linx: http://osxdaily.com/2010/11/21/find-ip-address-mac/

Make sure you are on the same wifi network on your phone and your mac.

Go to your phone and type in your ip + :3000, e.g. 192.168.1.5:3000.

Ta da.